# Postgres and Visual studio asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, visual-studio, postgresql

How can I add a postgresql database to a Visual studio asp .net project? I have tried by downloading the postgres odbc driver but still I can't see it in the odbc menu and is there any other way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Most Visual Studio versions are 32-bit applications, even when installed on 64-bit Windows. The ODBC driver must match the application architecture, not the PostgreSQL server architecture.

Install the 32-bit ODBC driver.